# Почему функция вызывается один раз

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Нужно чтобы она(функция) вызывалась столько раз, сколько будет кликов по кнопке. Но вот сейчас, она вызывается всего один раз и дальше прекращает что-либо делать.

```
$(".plus").click(function()
{
    var productArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("productData")) || [];
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

    productArray[id]["count"]++;
    localStorage.setItem("productData", JSON.stringify(productArray));
    $(".product-counter").eq(id+1).html(productArray[id]["count"]+'<div class="count-changer"><div class="minus change" data-id="'+id+'">-</div><div class="plus change" data-id="'+id+'">+</div></div>')

    console.log(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что Ваш элемент `".plus"` находится внутри `".product-counter"`. Назначая html родителю, Вы пересоздаете все, что в нем находится. У этих вновь созданных элементов нет никаких обработчиков событий.

```
$(".product-counter").on("click", ".plus", function()
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое;)*

Comment: @Istinnavvine Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.